# Javascript & JQuery: how to bind the value to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Given below is part of my website

```
   <body controller="contr">
       <h1 bind="greeting"></h1>
        <p bind="text"></p>
   </body>
```

I need to bind the values of contr properties

```
   contr.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
   contr.text = 'Lorem Ipsum ..';
```

to h1 and p tags when:

```
     if controller == 'contr'
```

so it will be interpreted as

```
     <h1 bind="greeting">Hello, World!</h1>
     <p bind="text">Lorem Ipsum ..</p>
```

How I can implement this in JQuery? What is best source to learn more about such DOM binding with JS and JQuery

Comment: Never seen bind="" before like that. Why don't you use a data-bind="" or use a class type?

Comment: Are you using Angular JS?

Comment: @Grimbode this is main problem, I don't know what 'controller' and 'bind' attributes that are used here. there is no framework. that's why I am confused how to do dom binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 bind="greeting">Jasper</h1>

<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("h1[bind='greeting']").html('Hello World');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

if it is not necessary, to use the bind attribute...

Define your Html code:

```
 <body id="contr">
   <h1 class="greeting"></h1>
    <p class="text"></p> </body>
```

JQuery Script code:

```
var greeting=  $("#contr").find(".greeting");
var text= $("#contr").find(".text");
greeting.html("Hello World!");
text.html("Lorem Ipsum ..");
```

otherwise use $("xxx").attr("bind","value");

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#greeting').html('Hello, World!');
  $('#text').html('Lorem Ipsum ..');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="greeting"></h1>
<p id="text"></p>
<button>Bind</button>
```

If you want to use bindings and controllers you need to use mvw framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).